# postgresql UPDATE on condition with group of id's

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

```
------------------------------------------
auto_id    | group_id  | TOF   | TOF_2 | 
------------------------------------------
8001       | 512       | true  |       | 
------------------------------------------
8002       | 512       | false |       | 
------------------------------------------
8003       | 512       | false |       | 
------------------------------------------
8004       | 512       | false |       | 
------------------------------------------
8005       | 512       | false |       | 
------------------------------------------
```

I want to `UPDATE` column `TOF_2` on a condition which can be described as follows: If any row of the same `group_id` shows a `TRUE`, all rows of this `group_id` should be filled with a `TRUE` (regardless of any other row showing a `FALSE` in this `group_id`) in column `TOF_2`.

I think an IF or CASE could solve the problem, but I'm not sure about the right expression?

```
UPDATE table
SET TOF_2 = CASE
    WHEN TOF is true THEN TOF_2 = true ELSE TOF_2 = FALSE
GROUP BY group_id
```

I know that this is wrong, but may be it leads in the right direction? It is somehow not easy to verbalize the task.

Comment: You can use `WHERE EXISTS` to check for the existance of a row with desired properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator with a subquery:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    tof2 = TRUE
WHERE  group_id IN  (SELECT group_id
                     FROM   my_table
                     WHERE  tof = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS` to check for this:

```
UPDATE a SET tof_2=true WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a a1 WHERE a1.group_id=a.group_id AND tof=true);
```